# how to write query for distinct value in spring mongodb

Tags: mysql, spring, mongodb

Unlike we write in SQL a query to select some value (say username) where some value (say kumar) is found.

```
SELECT username FROM usertable WHERE lastname IN (kumar)
```

what query do we use in spring mongo to select distinct value of "kumar" where "username" is found. I have tried to do this but the result is not as expected.

```
@Query(value="{'username':?0}",fields="{'lastname':1}")
```

I am getting the list of lastname but not distinct value of last name.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct` method of `MonogTemplate`

```
mongoTemplate.getCollection("collection_name").distinct("lastname", new BasicDBObject("username", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)));
```